# AngularJS - Keep Checking Variable/Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know what is the best way to keep checking a variable in AngularJS.

I made a simple clicker game where the user keeps gathering gold, so I need to be constantly checking the number of gold so I can perform some functions accordingly. The only thing I know is $interval, but I don't know if that's the best way since I have to write a number of seconds.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wherever your variable is stored (controller/directive):

```
$scope.goldAmount = 0; // or whatever initial value you so desire
```

Set a watch function

```
$scope.$watch('goldAmount', function(newAmount, oldAmount){
  // Do something with the amount when it changes
});
```

`$watch` allows you to 'watch' any variable within your `$scope` and run a call back when it changes.

Docs can be found here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: I'm reading it right now and trying to learn how it works. Thank you.